# What is the default ColorFunction for Image3D?

Tags: color, implementation-details, image3d

What is the default `ColorFunction` for [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html)?  I find it a bit confusing that the most intense colour is not shown where the highest values appear:

```
data = Table[
   Exp[-3 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], {x, -1., 1, .01}, {y, -1., 
    1, .01}, {z, -1., 1, .01}];

Image3D[data, ClipRange -> {{100, 200}, {0, 200}, {100, 200}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Automatic] (* default colour function *)
```

[image]

Note that the bright yellow is not in the middle of the sphere.  I wanted to understand what causes this effect (possibly some interplay of opacity and colours?).  Otherwise I like the default.  Did anyone try to reconstruct the default `ColorFunction` for `Image3D`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the documentation of Image3D, "an interactive color function editor is available via the Image3D contextual (right-click) menu". (And yes! I only found it after reading your question!)

[image: contextual menu]

[image: ColorFunction editor]

And you can get the explicit function by clicking the "Copy Function" button.

```
Blend[{
       {0., RGBColor[0.05635, 0.081, 0.07687, 0.00343663]},
       {0.1, RGBColor[0.8877, 0.2636, 0., 0.103093]},
       {0.3, RGBColor[1., 0.6036, 0., 0.302406]},
       {0.66, RGBColor[1., 0.9658, 0.4926, 0.661168]},
       {1., RGBColor[1., 0.6436, 0.03622, 1.]}
      }, #1] &
```

Comment: I feel stupid now.  I never noticed that!

Comment: @Szabolcs I doubt anyone noticed :)

Comment: I didn't know that! A new world of possibilities... *_*

Comment: That looks awfully like Wolfram's version of MATLAB's `hot()` colormap…

Comment: @J. M. Woww! Long time no see! Welcome back! :DD

Comment: Somewhat back, yes. Thanks @Silvia!

Comment: @Silvia What is your system? I am having memory problems with the code in Mathematica 11 of Debian 8.5, thread here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311921/16920

Comment: @Masi If my memory is correct, it was Windows 8 64bit. Regarding your problem, I think you might get more help from the WRI company. They are more expert than any users and they might already have some solutions.

Comment: @Silvia Do you mean by WRI company the Wolfram Support? - - I already contacted them about the problem - now, waiting for their answer.

Comment: @Masi Sorry for the acronym. Yes WRI = Wolfram Research, Inc. I think their support is your best chance for solving the problem.