# Limited Opacity Levels in Image3D?

Tags: image3d

I'm trying to render a simple spherical distribution where the opacity varies with radius using `Image3D`. Unfortunately, the outcome is not very appealing, with discrete colors showing up in the rendering:

[image]

You can see that not only are the colors discrete, they are not even in order, with some darker bands appearing in the image in the lighter regions, whereas the image should have the appearance of a smooth radial gradient.

The code I used to generate the above image is:

```
res = 100;
coords = Table[{i, j, k} - 0.5, {i, Range@res}, {j, Range@res}, {k, Range@res}];
dists = Map[N@Norm[# - res/2.] &, coords, {3}];
opa = 1/(dists + 0.1);
opa /= Max@opa;
ImageAdjust@Image3D[opa, ColorFunction -> "GrayOpacity"]
```

My question is if there are limitations for opacity in `Image3D`, and if so, are there ways around it?

Comment: In V9 I don't see the "alternating" effect

Comment: [This is what I get](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rl9km.png)

Comment: @belisarius I'm using V9 on OS X. Even if the banding is absent, the discrete color levels are undesirable, which I still see in your output.

Comment: There is a question somewhere about Opacity having a sharp cutoff (ie not being able to represent low gray values). Probably a hint that it's working with discrete values.

Comment: I know that some volume renderers do only 256 discrete levels (IDL being an ancient example). I was hoping it was a global rendering option that perhaps was causing this.

Comment: Have you tried other  predefined color functions?

Comment: Yeah I tried a few others, all show similar behavior. A constant opacity also doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this panel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38337/17).

Comment: @Silvia I tried tinkering with that a bit, couldn't get any satisfactory results.

Comment: @Guillochon I think the main problem is the large area of low gray values. If it were me, I would try clipping them out, e.g. `Rescale[Clip[opa,{.08,1}],{.08,1}][[30;;70,30;;70,30;;70]]//Image3D[#,ColorFunction->"GrayOpacity"]&`.

Comment: Why the colors should not be discrete when you are using 100 discrete levels? Of course they are discrete. Try using small `res=3` or `res=5` you will see exactly `3` levels or `5` levels of gray respectively. It is the same with `res=100` just that now there are `100` levels.

Comment: @azerbajdzan you can still see discreetness of opacity levels.

Answer (score -1):

Your understandig is not appropriate. You use cartesian coordinate and wonder why the result is not spherical. You remain on the cartesion grid and only assign each cube a spherical calculated value of a combined gray level with opacity.

The problem is not changed by

```
res = 10;
coords = Table[{Sqrt[i^2 + j^2 + k^2], ArcTan[k, Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]], 
    ArcTan[i, j]}, {i, -res, res}, {j, -res, res}, {k, -res, res}];
dists = Map[N@Norm[# - .5] &, coords[[All, All, All, 1]], {3}];
opa = 1/(dists + 0.3);
opa /= Max@opa;
ImageAdjust@Image3D[opa, ColorFunction -> "GrayOpacity"]
```

[image: more spherical result]

Some small turn and You see the cubes much clearer:

[image: after a small turn].

res is not the right parameter to get the desired shading!
The very same is in Your solution at work.

The documentation page for [DelaunayMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) shows an example how to avoid cubic volume grids in Mathematica:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 3}];
Rsc = DelaunayMesh[pts];
HighlightMesh[Rsc, {Style[0, 
   Directive[PointSize[Medium], Black]], Style[2, Opacity[0.1]]}]
```

[image]

Your procedure path may be Delauney mesh spheres stacked in each other and assign the volumes of this mesh elements gray levels and opactiy. Then increase res again.

This guide list [Solid Geometry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SolidGeometry.html) what is in Mathematica. [`Cone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cone.html) has some samples how this looks on the basis of `Cone` and `Circle` in color.

[Sphere](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere.html) show some example: Place Sphere instead of Cube. The main problem is that Mathematica visualizes surfaces instead of volumes by primitives. A volume is represented by the boundary and that is in 3D a surface. The professional term is tessalation. Boundaries are reprensented at most by `Polygons`. The shadings are achieved if desires by Your res parameter alike parameters. This relies on a scene graph like structure and that is it.

But as shown in [`Volume`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Volume.html) Mathematica has both MeshRegion and MeshBoundaryRegion. The built-in [MeshPrimitives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html) should suit Your question real hidden intent, but it does not of-the-shelf. Sphere meshing is problematic in Mathematica, [surface-mesh-of-a-hemisphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163088/surface-mesh-of-a-hemisphere). Have a look at this: [draw-a-triangulated-sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141429/draw-a-triangulated-sphere) This answer [how-to-discretize-a-sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817605/how-to-discretize-a-sphere) suggests

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]
G = Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"], 5] // N;
Graphics3D@G
```

[image]
as discrete closed accurate approximation of the Sphere. It is suitable for Your intent. Or more random: [voronoi grid on a sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139457/voronoi-grid-on-a-sphere/142100).

Or use my full example and increase $res$ and optimize the left over parameters. So chose a different distribution with a sharper upper drop. For example Fermi or piecewise, step function and alike.

This is a counterexample:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[a], Black, Specularity[White, 5], Sphere[]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"], {a, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image: Opacity in action]

This shows up clearly the concept of Mathematica Graphics3D and color and lighting and opacity. And it works. The Sphere is special and somewhat cheating the critical human eye. That is all. No second level or higher. The documentation of [`Specularity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Specularity.html) clearly state that [`Specularity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Specularity.html) does not work with flat 3D surface. You are making use of flat 3D surfaces.

Another example:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[a], GrayLevel[.25], Specularity[White, 10], 
   Sphere[]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"], {a, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[a], Glow[Black], White, Sphere[]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"], {a, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[Exp[-.15/(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> None]
```

[image]

```
Table[DensityPlot3D[
  Exp[-.5/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], {x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[], 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
  OpacityFunction -> Function[f, (1 - f)^2], Boxed -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> pp], {pp, {50, 75, 100}}]
```

[image]

The more plotpoints the smoother.

Or make use of the `DensityPlot` as a texture on the `Sphere`.

[image]

[image]

Make use of the image dimensions in the parameter set for ImageSize.

The great trick with `Raster` will help it further the last step.

Comment: The issue of discrete opacity still persists even without spherical elements. Try DensityPlot3D[Exp[-Abs[Max[x, y, z]]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, OpacityFunction -> Function[f, f]]

Comment: The first part was to answer the question as tight as possible and to go into details. DensitiyPlot make use of a rectangular grid too there is no real change. But that is for sure not the limit in Mathematica.