# Is there a 3D Voronoi function in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

I use Mathematica v11.1.

I made a vase by rotating the graph with Mathematica.

```
f[x_] := Sin[0.8 x] + 1.5;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 7.5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01],
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 3/7]
RevolutionPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 7.5},
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.3], RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, 
    BoxRatios -> {7.5, 6, 6}, PlotPoints -> 50,Mesh -> None]
```

[image]
[image]

I would like to make Voronoi form as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Is there a 3D Voronoi function in Mathematica? Or, I want to know a good way.

Comment: not out of the box, here's something to work with: [Voronoi tessellations on meshed surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141348/5478)