# Draw a triangulated sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How to draw a triangulated sphere such as the one below in *Mathematica*, without being restricted to these colors, but with a more uniform color (possibly with some shaded area), and with the background frame removed?

[image: triangulated sphere]

Comment: Which version are you in? You can get this type of deal using the region functionality pretty easily.

Comment: Use `Geodesate[]` from the Polyhedron Operations package (``Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]``), or use the region discretization functionality on a `Sphere[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Problem with `RegionDiscretize` is the coloring. It's a bit of a pain to color each cell, last I remembered. I'm currently trying it with `Lighting`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're a) on 10+ and b) don't need this cells to truly be colored, you can try this:

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion@Sphere[];

MeshRegion[mesh,
 Lighting -> Sequence @@@ {
    ConstantArray[{"Point", Red, {0, 0, 75}}, 2],
    Map[{"Point", Yellow, Append[#, 0]} &,
     CirclePoints[3., 6]
     ],
    ConstantArray[{"Point", Blue, {0, 0, -75}}, 2]
    },
 MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> Black}
 
 ]
```

[image: withmesh]

This is just tricking you into thinking it's colored using `Lighting`. I was too lazy to highlight each cell. It's possible to write code to color an arbitrary discretized surface at the cell level. I've done it, but it's more code than I want to post here and isn't thoroughly proof-read. If you need that I can dig it up from wherever it's hiding, though.

#### Update

OP mentions in the comments that he's really interested in the triangulation. That's easily extracted as such:

```
triangulation =
  With[{cds = MeshCoordinates@mesh},
   MeshCells[mesh, 2] /. i_Integer :> cds[[i]]
   ];
```

And just to check that we pulled it out right:

```
triangulation // Graphics3D
```

[image: triangulation]

Comment: Thanks, but I hope to have the "triangulated" grid for the math purpose. (Not for the art purpose.)

Comment: @wonderich Then your life is _much_ easier. Use `MeshCoordinates`. I'll post an addendum.

Comment: @wonderich Added.

Comment: +1 for `Lighting`.BTY,`MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> Black}` is more similar with OP

Comment: @MB1965 thanks for lesson on `Lighting` +1 :)

Comment: @yode Nice point. I included it.

Comment: Have you noted we cannot make that triangle be more lager when we discretize a sphere?

Comment: And we can use `MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]`

Comment: @yode you can probably increase the mesh size in the discretize call. I just remembered about SliceDensityPlot3D which solves the OPs problem better. Unable to post it right now, though, so feel free to put it out there SliceDensityPlot3D[z, mesh, {x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1},{z,-1,1},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"] should do it.

Comment: Your `SliceDensityPlot3D` work well,just we cannot set the edge be `Black`.

Comment: @yode use /._EdgeForm->EdgeForm[Black]

Comment: I post it as a answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141435/21532).And I have specified that is your work. :)

Comment: Thanks again, I wonder whether there is a way to change the number of triangulation (to fewer triangles)?

Comment: @wonderich Sure there is. You'd change it in the discretize call. See the various other answers for an example. In part two of yode's answer I tweaked things to basically exactly reproduce your picture. Did that by reducing how fine a mesh it triangulated.

Comment: In your first part answer, using "MeshRegion" -- what values should I adjust to change the number of triangulations? Thanks!

Comment: @wonderich It's actually in the the call to `DiscretizeRegion` that you'll want to change things. Try `mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure->{"Length" -> .35}, PrecisionGoal -> .01]`. That's what I used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141435/38205)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps,

```
r = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]];
pg = MeshPrimitives[r, 2];
Graphics3D[
 pg /. Polygon[
    u___] :> {ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[Max[u[[All, 3]]], {-1, 1}]], Polygon[u]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]:

Exploiting [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141438/1997)

```
Manipulate[
 r = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> lg}, PrecisionGoal -> 0.01];
 pg = MeshPrimitives[r, 2];
 Graphics3D[
  pg /. Polygon[
     u___] :> {ColorData["Rainbow"][
      Rescale[Max[u[[All, 3]]], {-1, 1}]], Polygon[u]}, 
  Axes -> True], {lg, {0.1, 0.5, 1, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ubpdqn Ahh. Of course. Going straight to the `Graphics3D` is much better.

Answer (score 4):

### Method One

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion@Sphere[];
Graphics3D[Transpose[{ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
    Rescale[Last /@ PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]], 
   MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]}]]
```

[image]

### Method two(Based on [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141429/draw-a-triangulated-sphere/141432?noredirect=1#comment382175_141432))

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]];
SliceDensityPlot3D[z, mesh, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] /. _EdgeForm -> EdgeForm[Black]
```

[image]

#### MB1965 tweaks to Method two:

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[],
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .35},
   PrecisionGoal -> .01];
SliceDensityPlot3D[z,
  mesh, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  FaceGrids ->
   -IdentityMatrix[3],
  AxesEdge -> {
    {-1, 1},
    {1, -1},
    {1, -1}
    },
  Boxed -> False
  ] /. _EdgeForm -> EdgeForm[Black]
```

[image]

Comment: @MB1965 Perfect.Sorry cannot upvote. :)

Comment: I just realized we have three different ways Mathematica can do coloring on this page. This way here clearly uses layered textures, because there are gradients in the cells. The `Lighting` way does colors in the rendering system. And the way @ubpqdn did it colors individual faces. Pretty cool for such a simple question.