# How to get a larger triangle when we discretize a sphere?

Tags: regions, mesh, discretization

In order to solve [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141429/draw-a-triangulated-sphere),I want to get larger triangles (Of course less amount). But I don't know how to do this. I have tried `MaxCellMeasure` and `MeshRefinementFunction`, but this doesn't work

```
DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 10]
```

and

```
DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], 
 MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vertices, area}, area > 10]]
```

Always gives

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: There's a limit, of course: the tetrahedron.

Comment: @J.M. You mean we cannot get another mount triangle?

Comment: Think about it: can you cover a sphere with three triangles?

Comment: @J.M. Fun,It's seem [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141438/21532) answer response your question..:)

Comment: That's an icosahedron (twenty triangles), so still far away from the limit of four. ;)

Comment: @J.M. I note `4,6,8..` also can cover a sphere..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the following:

```
a = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 3}, PrecisionGoal -> 0.01]
```

`Length` determines the size of the triangulation

which gives:

[image: discretised surface]

Comment: Amazing,I don't know we can use `MaxCellMeasure` like this..

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to force it to show an octahedron, much less a tetrahedron.

Comment: Why not `DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]...]` :)

Comment: True ;) i.e. `DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 3}, PrecisionGoal -> 0.01]` would also work

Comment: or `DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]`