# Surface mesh of a hemisphere

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

While trying to create a surface mesh of a hemisphere

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
halfsphere = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]
reg = DiscretizeRegion[halfsphere]
```

I get  the expected plot [image],

but some questions remain:

- How could I show the mesh of reg?
- Why isn't it possible to create an elementmesh from reg?
  `ToElementMesh[reg]`
  `(* ToElementMesh::femtemnm: A mesh could not be generated. *)`
- How could I extract the boundary (equator)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For first question:

```
MeshRegion[reg, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
```

or

```
MeshRegion[reg, PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

or

```
MeshRegion[reg, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

To find the equator you could use FindMeshDefects:

```
boundary = FindMeshDefects[reg, "HoleEdges", "Cell"]["HoleEdges"]
```

> {{Line[{392, 460, 464, 911, 978, 1029, 1086, 1137, 1184, 1235, 1286, 
>       1339, 1390, 1457, 1512, 1537, 569, 570, 637, 638, 701, 702, 769, 
>       765, 766, 817, 813, 856, 853, 849, 844, 839, 834, 829, 824, 820, 
>       778, 773, 717, 710, 705, 647, 641, 579, 573, 476, 475, 1516, 1463,
>        1393, 1343, 1291, 1241, 1190, 1143, 1092, 1035, 983, 917, 857, 
>       401, 400, 337, 264, 263, 196, 195, 121, 120, 129, 63, 62, 1, 7, 
>       12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 47, 51, 54, 110, 114, 180, 186, 189, 254, 
>       257, 326, 329, 392}]}}

```
HighlightMesh[reg, boundary]
```

Comment: Great idea, using "HoleEdges", thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ulrich, please have a look at the documentation. For example, [ToBoundaryMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html), [ToElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) and the [Element Mesh Generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) have plenty of information.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
halfsphere = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}];
reg = ToBoundaryMesh[halfsphere];
reg["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

For the equator you could look at [ElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html) and the mentioned "BoundaryConnectivity" or "VertexBoundaryConnectivity"

If you want to extract the coords use something like:

```
Cases[reg[
  "Coordinates"], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?(Abs[#] <= 10^-3. &)}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. If I consider a little more complex problem, which I tried to prepare with my question:  A closed curve,  on the sphere cuts the sphere in two parts. How would I mesh such a surface?

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the documentation:

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[halfsphere, 
MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> Black}, MaxCellMeasure -> .005]
```

[image]

You can play with `MaxCellMeasure` value.

Now, you have a 2D region, so you have to use `ToBoundaryMesh`:

```
ToBoundaryMesh[halfsphere]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

And finally, I am assuming you need the coordinates of the resulting mesh for the equator:

```
Cases[ToBoundaryMesh[halfsphere, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}]["Wireframe"][[1, 2, 1]]
, {__, __, 0.}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I've learned a lot, especially, that a surface in space cannot be constructed using ToElementMesh[].